# Unzip a list of tuples with variable number of elements

Tags: python, zip, tuples, unzip

I want to unzip a list of tuples, `zipped`, of the following form:

```
zipped1 = [(a, b, c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i)]
```

using

```
x, y, z = zip(*zipped1)
```

However, the number of elements in each tuple is variable; the list can as well look like this:

```
zipped2 = [(a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h)]
```

How can I unzip these two list of tuples with the same command?

Comment: Why not store the result in a single list or tuple?

Comment: Why not `unzipped = zip(*zipped1)`?

Comment: I am little bit confused, whats your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what iterables are for. If you do not know in advance how many objects (of any kind) you expect, do not work with individually named variables, but put them all in a `list`, `tuple` or generator:

```
z = ['abcd', 'efgh']
transposed = list(zip(*z))
# [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]
```

Now you can iterate and process  whatever number of tuples there are in the transposed matrix.